# How to Save the value of a select option declared in componentDidmount method for use in all components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

'm fetching an API from a source. And it was successful. But I want the value of the selected option to save when clicked, but whenever, I click on it, It shows and after I move to another section and move back to it, it would have reset itself.

I have a login form with steps, steps are like -> Next and previous button, just to save and navigate to next from till the last input, then submit. And I fetched an API with `componentDidmount` method. It worked so fine, but whenever I clicked on the select dropdown options and I choose an option, it worked, and If I move to the next step, other inputs will get saved but it will not be saved.

Here's my code.

```
//my componentDidmount method

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            skills: null
         };
    }

    fetchSkills = () => {
        fetch('https://my_api_link')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(skills => {
            this.setState({
                skills: skills.map(s => s.ssp_skill_name)
            })
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchSkills();
    }
```

```
//how I used it

<div className="form-group mb-4" style={{maxWidth: "25rem"}}>
      <label htmlFor="skills">Skills:</label>
        {this.state.skills && (
           <select className="form-control email_input">
            {this.state.skills.map(s => (
               option key={s}>{s}</option>
             ))}
         </select>
       )}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the myriad of libs to support this case ([useSWR](https://github.com/vercel/swr), [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/), [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/), [easy-peasy](https://easy-peasy.now.sh/), and more and more). But if you wish to implement a solution without new deps, you can leverage [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for that.

```
const skillsContext = React.createContext()

export default function SkillsContext(props) {
  const [skills, setSkills] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://my_api_link')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(skills => {
            setSkills(skills.map(s => s.ssp_skill_name))
        });
  },[]}

  return <skillsContext.Provider value={skills}>{props.children}</skillsContext.Provider>
}

export default useSkills = React.useContext(skillsContext)
```

place `<SkillContext>` at the root of your app, and then access the value with `useSkills` anywhere in your app.

---

if you're using the Component syntax, you can access it through a static `contextType` like so:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = SkillsContext

  render() {
    this.context
  }
}
```

Comment: if this is the answer you're looking for, please accept it. Otherwise what do I need to add?